# ruby Facebook app redirects outside of canvas after authorizing

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku, authorization

I made a simple Facebook application, using the automated hosting option from Heroku, selecting Ruby as the language.  The first time a user tries to use the app, the are asked to authorize.  After authorizing, they are redirected to the apps URL outside of the Facebook canvas.  How can I make them stay within the Facebook canvas after authorizing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect the users back to facebook from your app.
the facebook app url looks like http://apps.facebook.com/your-app-id

Comment: That would seem to be the simple solution, but then the application loads a blank canvas.  I'm using Mogli to handle authorization and I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.  Also, it seems the example app created by the automated Heroku/Facebook does the same thing.  It seems the example app should have the desired behavior.

Comment: similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831756/facebook-iframe-app-being-redirected-out-of-canvas-after-user-authorization.  If I could see the corrected controller here, it would help a lot, even though it's using Koala, not Mogli.