# Rails Facebook iframe app being redirected out of canvas after user authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, authorization, koala

This question was asked in another post at [Facebook iframe app being redirected out of canvas after user authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831756/facebook-iframe-app-being-redirected-out-of-canvas-after-user-authorization), however, I'm having the same problem and don't understand how to implement the fix described in the post.  If they posted the fixed controller, it would be awesome.  Here's my controller.

```
class AppController < ApplicationController

def index
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", "https://quiet-mist-8418.heroku.com/app/redirect" )
  if (session[:access_token].blank?)
    redirect_to @oauth.url_for_oauth_code and return
  end

  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
  @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends").to_s
end

def redirect
  @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", "https://quiet-mist-8418.heroku.com/app/redirect" )
  session[:access_token] = @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code]) if params[:code]
  redirect_to(:action=>"index")
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I went to the settings page of my the Facebook developer app, and made some changes to the settings > auth dialogue section, and it seems to be working as desired.  I checked the section marked, "authentication referrals."  Now, it stays on the page after authorizing.